# re: [MIPS] 100 characters String and printing it in 10 lines at a time. [assembly]

Tags: string, loops, assembly, mips

I'm having issues again solving these small task I got. Basically I got a board stored in 1 line, and I need to print 10 characters in 1 line and then break and so on. It's a board of 10 x 10, so it should run 10 times printing 10 character lines.

Something like this:

board:
    .asciiz     "    x xx   x  x      x  x  xxx x  x         x   x         x xxxx  x x       x   xx    x         x xx"

For this we got handed 2 subroutines, print and printlf. print takes in $a0 the string to print, and in $a1 the length, so I just need to jal print once I get the correct characters stored in the registers.

I was reading how to solve this on the internet and got to this [source](http://davidlovesprogramming.blogspot.de/2013/01/the-following-post-is-bit-more-complex.html).

```
write_board:
   ##TODO Implement your solution here ###

  sw $a1, size           #I save 10 in length a1
  la $t0, board          #load the board on t0
  add $t1, $zero, $zero  #counter in t1 set to 0 for chars
  add $t5, $zero, $zero  #counter in t5 for the 10 loops
  li $t3, 10             #10 for the division in t3

count:
  lb $t2, 0($t0)
  addi $t1, $t1, 1
  div $t1, $t3  
  mfhi $t4                   #the remainder of div is in t4
  beq $t4, $zero, lineBreak  #if its 0 then break
  j count   

lineBreak:
  sw $t2, 0($a0)             #save the first 10 chars in a0 for printing
  jal print
  jal print_lf
  addi $t5, $t5, 1           #there needs to be 10 prints, we add 1 everytime one happens
  beq $t5, $t3 endString     #if its 10, the program is over
  j count 

 endString:
    jr $ra

.data
  size:
 .word      10

 board:
    .asciiz     "    x xx   x  x      x  x  xxx x  x         x   x         x xxxx  x x       x   xx    x         x xx"
```

This doesn't seem to work on QTSpim, it gives this error: Exception occurred at PC=0x004000e4
  Unaligned address in store: 0x00000001

Anyone kind enough to maybe know a bug to this simple task yet hard for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sw $a1, size           #I save 10 in length a1` - not, that's not how `sw` works. Do you use MARS simulator, or one of SPIM ones? Check their help and instruction description and some tutorials and stuff, etc.. a do some experiment first with just few instructions, using debugger to single step over them, and to check if you understand what they do.

Comment: How do I save the arguments I need to print so that jal print prints them???

Comment: I have trouble to understand what you mean by save arguments... but I will try to focus on that very first line, from the comment I guess you want to set `a1` to value `10`.  Your `sw $a1, size` will store current value in `a1` into memory at address `size`, i.e. it will overwrite the value `10` with something in register (probably zero set up by the OS before running your code, maybe some other value). To load the value `10` from memory into `a1` you have to use `lw $a1, size`, "lw" = "load word" (sw = store word) ... "load" is reading memory, "store" is writing into memory.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, if you use MARS, so I will assume you use MARS (if you don't, then download it and try it, it may help you with MIPS basics too plus you can see what I mean). In MARS hit key "F1" to open help, and read about instructions, syscalls, etc... read also note area above instructions explaining addressing modes, etc... read it several times, and about each instruction you use, to somewhat adjust your dictionary to use the same terms as MARS help, so people familiar with MIPS assembly will better understand what you are trying to tell. And use single-step in debugger.

Comment: The code after first line, especially the count loop, doesn't make much sense in assembly, I can probably guess what was your intention while writing it, but it's not the logic by which the CPU operates (for example `lb $t2, 0($t0)` does not add to the `t2` next character, it will always load only single character and set up the `t2` to contain only the single one, so you read 10 characters to end with the last one = pointless loop) - maybe try first to search for some working examples of simple MARS/SPIM student tasks, and debug them in debugger to see how they work, start with simple ones.

Comment: If the task is too hard for you, contact your lector, or your class-mates, so you can work on it together. There's no point to write correct solution here in answer, because the task is extremely trivial, if you understand programming a bit, and did spend 2-3 days learning MIPS assembly under good lector guidance, so if this is too hard for you, you didn't study it properly, or you need to learn new ways of thinking to have your mind more "programming friendly", so you can guess better how to break tasks into algorithms, and small steps, which are then easier to code. May take some effort, GL.

Comment: Ok thank you. I understand what you mean. I use QTSpim, I don't know if there's any differences between this and MARS.

Comment: "I have trouble to understand what you mean by save arguments"

Comment: Basically, in the exercise we got handed a print subroutine, and a comment with something like $a0 --> string to print, $a1 -->length

Comment: My first question would be how to pass these arguments to the function, I'm guessing with what you said that I should load word.

Comment: How would I in this example get 10 characters into a register, and not 1 by 1?

Comment: those arguments are described a bit too short, it's highly likely the `a0` should contain memory address of string data (`la $a0,board`) and `a1` should contain integer value how many chars should be printed (`li $a1,10` or if you want to load it from `size` memory address `lw $a1,size`) ... try to write only these two + `jal print` and check in debugger what it does. SPIM is very similar to MARS, as the underlying MIPS emulation is same I think, but the GUI+editor is different. QtSPIM should have also debugger and help, although I didn't use it. What you learn in MARS will by 95% work in SPIM

Comment: And you can't get 10 characters into register, as long as we are talking about ASCII encoded string, because in ASCII encoding single character is 8 bit value, and MIPS register is 32 bits "wide", so you can at most pack 4 ASCII characters into one register, but that's not how string functions usually operate, usually string functions take memory address of first character, and work 1 by 1 with them up till the length of string specified (`a1` in your case), or when nul terminated strings are used, up until byte with value `0` is found (marking end of string). (memory address is 32b integer)

Comment: Plus you don't need to do anything with the board characters, etc.. the whole task is set up to be trivial, i.e. just calling 10 times the `print` subroutine with address `board + 10*i` (i=[0..9]) and size of string 10, and between to call newline subroutine. Your solution should be like ~10 lines of code, cca, without any serious logic (doing `board_adr += 10;` is not very complex), more like practice of calling subroutines and juggling a bit with registers to keep values intact between calls and load the correct a0/a1/... before each call.

Comment: Thank you for your input. A problem I have is I tend to make things more complicated. I was trying to loop every character and break every 10th character. But whatever, I misunderstood how you manipulate strings in MIPS.